# VBA will no longer send appointment to outlook

Tags: excel, vba, variables

My program iterates through an excel table and inputs them as an appointment into an outlook calendrer titled "Test". It was working fine but now I get error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set).

This occurs where the venous aspects for the appointment are defined; subject, start, finish, body and save.

I have rebooted since but that shouldn't have changed anything.

I wondered if it was because my references reset but that also doesn't seem to be the issue.

```
Option Explicit
Public oOutlook As Object
Public miCalendario As Object
Public objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Private Sub CalExport_Click()

    Const olAppointmentItem = 1
    Dim OBjapt As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim strFolderName As String
    Dim OLAppointment As Object

    Set OBjapt = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Calendar = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Test")
    Set objAppointment = Calendar.items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    Call StartOutlook

    B = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Value
    For A = 0 To B
        If A = Range("A7").Value Then
            A = B
        End If

        Set OLAppointment.Subject = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(X, 2).Value)
        SD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(X, 3).Value
        ST = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(X, 4).Value, "hh:mm:ss")
        SDT = FormatDateTime(SD & " " & ST)
        MsgBox SDT
        OLAppointment.Start = DateValue(SDT)

        ED = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(X, 5).Value
        ET = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(X, 6).Value, "hh:mm:ss")
        EDT = FormatDateTime(ED & " " & ET)
        OLAppointment.End = DateValue(EDT)

        OLAppointment.Body = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(X, 7).Value & vbNewLine & "Expected LAIR: " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(X, 8).Value & "%")

        OLAppointment.Save

        X = X - 1
    Next A

    Set OLAppointment = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Write `Option Explicit` above the code of each(!) module to prevent errors like "OLAppointment" vs. "objAppointment".

Comment: Sorry that line is at the top in my actual program.

Comment: You declare `objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem`, but your code uses `OLAppointment`. They're not the same. `obj` <> `OL`. Fix that first. If the problem remains, step through the code in the debugger to determine which specific line causes the error and the current values of all variables used are at that time.

Comment: Along with the variable name conflicts mentioned.  does `Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).` need some sort of prefixing to get from the outlook object.  Also, what does startoutlook do, should this be at the start?

Comment: None of these suggestions may solve your current problem but they will all improve your code.

Comment: `Sheets(2)` accesses a worksheet based on its position within the tab list.  If the user changes the sequence of the tabs, `Sheets(2)` will no longer be the list you wish to process.  `Sheets("AppointmentList")` would be more reliable.

Comment: `Range("A65536")` identified the bottom cell of column A with Excel 2003.  `Cells(Rows.Count, )` will work for all versions of Excel.

Comment: Please do not use names such as `A` or `B` or `X`.  You might know what they mean now but will you remember in six or twelve months when you need to update your macro?

Comment: `A` is the control variable of a for loop.  You cannot change a control variable within the loop so `A = B` is not allowed.  I believe `Exit For` is the statement you want.

Comment: You use X as a row offset without initialising it.

Comment: It is very difficult to guess what your code it trying to do.  It appears the first loop will read values out of the last row of the worksheet using `Offset(X, #)`.  You then increment X so the next loop will read values out of the first blank row.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Your code relies on the worksheet never changing.  This code is fragile so I am not surprised it stopped working.  What happens if cell “A7” moves?  What happens if any of the columns move?  Please use constants to access columns. For example `Const ColSubject as Long = 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `OLAppointment` everywhere, but it seems that this variable is not defined anywhere. You do however use `objAppointment`. I think you should change `OLAppointment` to `objAppointment`

Comment: sorry I left that out when I copied it across the variable is now defined

Comment: It is defined, but where is it set?

Answer (score -1):

Cheers Everyone,

Just had to use objAppointment not OLAppointment. Very strange that it was working before. I often find VBA auto corrects its self.

Comment: How is this different from what I said in my answer?

Comment: Please do not write your resulting comment as an additional answer - as it is not an answer. You may write it below your question (by editing it) or - better - just write it as a comment directly below the correct answer of @Alex